# Import from HubSpot COS into Wordpress 4?

Tags: theme-development, themes, import, export

I've been having *zero* luck finding any information on *how-to* migrate an existing site (HusbSpot COS) into a WordPress site.

Does anyone know of any existing documentation (or suggestions) on the subject?

Edit: I've been able to migrate the 'content' via the RSS import, but still looking for some guidance / suggestions on moving the look & feel [theme]

Answer (score 0):

> but still looking for some guidance / suggestions on moving the look
>   & feel [theme]

Content Management Systems like WordPress separate the content from the design. You have the content; you now need the design.

So you need to look at the HTML and CSS at Hubspot and read http://codex.wordpress.org/Theme_Development to see how to convert the design to a Wordpress theme.

Comment: Thanks for pointing me in the right direction; there's (more) than a few CSS files (18) in the export, I'm guessing it's going to be a process of elimination.